# exception while assigning values in label in custom cell

Tags: iphone

I have an table view where i am loaded custom cell from different nib, i am getting exception:

```
 2011-05-18 18:01:00.323 custInfoService[4370:20b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-984.38/UITableView.m:4709
2011-05-18 18:01:00.324 custInfoService[4370:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
2011-05-18 18:01:00.325 custInfoService[4370:20b] Stack: (
    11125851,
    2442997307,
```

When i used breakpoint then i come to know the xception is in switch case.I am not able to figure out why its giving exception?? help me!
here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) 
    { 
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BookDetailViewController" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = nibloadedcell;
       }

    tbcel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    tbcel.text = aBook.Name;


    UILabel *fieldlabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    fieldlabel.text = [fieldarray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
    UILabel *valuelabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
    switch(indexPath.section)

    {
        case 0:
            valuelabel.text = aBook.Address;
            break;
        case 1:
            valuelabel.text = aBook.Phone;
            break;
        case 2:
             valuelabel.text = aBook.Purchase;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the most obvious problem is that

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BookDetailViewController" owner:self options:NULL];
cell = nibloadedcell;
```

is not setting your `nibloadedcell` outlet, so `cell` is `nil` all the way through. Hence no valid cell is returned, and you get the error `UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Don't forget, messages to `nil` are silently disregarded - the rest of the function can execute fine if cell is `nil`, and just not do anything!

Comment: thank you... i was making silly mistake, :)  nib name was "bookdetailviewcontrollercell" and i was using the above that i have written.

Comment: @user720235: if his answer solved your problem, you should mark it as answered, so he can get credit and others can see.